# Tendon strenghtening with overspeed eccentrics

Tags: exercise, injury, health, injury-prevention, exercise-technique

"Microtrauma can occur when the patellar tendon is subjected to extreme forces such as rapid acceleration -deceleration, jumping, and landing."  - North American Journal of Sports Physical Therapy : NAJSPT

Does this mean that overspeed eccentrics such as when doing plyometrics and when using bands or simply lowering weights fast are a good way to strengthen the joints and prevent injury?

For example curling a barbell up as fast as possible then letting it drop down fast is supposed to strengthen the elbow, right or does it only work for the knee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [The study you are referring to](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2971642/#B4) was describing those microtrauma as the **cause** of tendinopathy, not as a means of strengthening tendons.

Overspeed eccentric exertion is likely to cause injury, not prevent it.